# "Needs debugging details" vs. "Needs details or clarity" - When should I pick what?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

If one wants to vote to close a question, there are two very similar reasons possible:

#### 1.

> "**Needs details or clarity**"
>
> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

#### 2. (Under "**A community-specific reason (too old to migrate)**")

> "**Needs debugging details**"
>
> The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

I still have problems when to choose what.

Is 1. only for cases when there is a general lack of information and 2. is actually for providing issuing code, clarifying problems with code, etc.?

When shall I use what? I want to keep Stack Overflow clean, but I just don’t know what is more appropriate to a specific question.

Comment: As I understand it, these two close reasons have now been merged into:
*Needs improvement
This question needs updates from the author in order to be answered well or belongs on another Stack Exchange site.*

Comment: No. That only appears in reviews.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While there is some overlap, a question may be fundamentally unclear and yet not be a *debugging* question.

Asking for for debugging details in those cases wouldn't be appropriate. And for debugging questions, when what you want is a reproducible example, the other close reason is less informative.

**If the question is a debugging question and lacks the necessary code to reproduce it, one should choose *"needs debugging details"*.** In those cases the question is (or may be) clear enough to be understandable, it simply lacks the necessary information to be answerable.

On the other hand, **if there is simply not enough information to actually understand question or the intent, the first reason (*"needs details or clarity"*)** would be more appropriate.

Comment: Isn´t almost any question on Stack Overflow more or less, explicitly or implicitly related to code and therefore it would be useful to provide the actual reference one has? (I might be wrong, just my actual assumption)

Comment: My rule of thumb - are you **unable** to understand what the question asks? It's unclear. Unless it's related to debugging code, that is. If you are **able** to understand it but don't want to answer because there is too much to cover (multiple questions, or one very, very wide one), then it needs focus.

Comment: @Robert Not all questions are deubgging questions or absolutely need to provide code. Maybe a majority, but there are many very useful **and on-topic** questions that are not about debugging and do not require to provide code. (Although there are many questions that even if not about debugging would benefit from some code, but that's a different thing).

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio not all questions are debugging questions. For example, you can have "How do I do X" which doesn't have any code from the user in it. That's not a debugging question. Might not even be an on-topic question, either.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio another frequent question that's not a debugging one is "Here is some code, why does it work that way" seeking explanation. These are not for finding problems but figuring out the operation of something.

Comment: A quick litmus test I use: An unclear question with an error message/description -> lacks debugging details, an unclear question without an error message/description -> unclear.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Well this one is about a behavior without need for code in itself and the exemple doesn't help if you don't know the inners (more an invocation thing) https://stackoverflow.com/q/32619688 while this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/31564651/3627607 wouldn't be properly answerable without a minimal exemple to understand where the author fail to understand the language behavior. I could have answered the first one by pure knowledge without exemple, the second one does need the exemple to understand the author problem IMHO.

Comment: Regretfully I had to downvote this answer, not because I believe it unsensible, but because it doesn't accord with reality in my experience. I have found many examples of questions which were closed with "needs clarity or detail", even after being understood and receiving good answers. I wish this answer were factual, rather than ideological; SO would be a better place.